# Google Ads tracking template

Tags: google-ads

I am setting up a conversion ad where I would have to set a tracking template. The ad would link to a Google form for sign up.

[image]

Are there any workarounds for the error?

Comment: What is the full value you have in the Final URL Suffix field?

Answer (score 1):

Here you will learn more about templates and their tracking. Tracking pattern: definition - Google Ads Help

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7197008?hl=uk